# Generic Inquiry / Fonction Concat

Tags: acumatica

When using the concat function with certain fields, it does not respect the content.
=Concat(CStr([Account.AccountCD]),' / ',CStr([Account.Description]))

In this example, the Accountcd field is missing

[image]

Comment: Could you please add the xml file for the GI to the question?

Comment: You can find the xml file : grosfi.ch/uBxMwz8v8mr ; Thanks !

Comment: I just imported your GI and it works fine for me https://ibb.co/9rnzmCY

Comment: Samvel, Thanks, I will see if this is the version